# Undefined namespace 'boost'

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying an C++ small thread program but having error that i couldn't handle it.

The Code

```
#include "Threads.h"
#include "Interthread.h"


void* task1(void *arg) {
// do stuff
}

void task2() {
// do stuff
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
using namespace boost;
Thread thread_1;
thread_1.start (task1,NULL);
// Thread thread_2 = thread(task2);

// do other stuff
//thread_2.join();
thread_1.join ();
return 0;
```

The Error

Test.cpp:15:21: error: ‘boost’ is not a namespace-name
Test.cpp:15:26: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token

The declaration of Thread Class

```
    class Thread {

    private:

    pthread_t mThread;
    pthread_attr_t mAttrib;
    // FIXME -- Can this be reduced now?
    size_t mStackSize;


    public:

    /** Create a thread in a non-running state. */
    Thread(size_t wStackSize = (65536*4)):mThread((pthread_t)0) {mStackSize=wStackSize;}

    /**
            Destroy the Thread.
            It should be stopped and joined.
    */
    ~Thread() { int s = pthread_attr_destroy(&mAttrib); assert(s==0); }


    /** Start the thread on a task. */
    void start(void *(*task)(void*), void *arg);

    /** Join a thread that will stop on its own. */
    void join() { pthread_join(mThread,NULL); }

     };
```

Comment: You don't seem to be including any of the Boost headers...

Comment: /me grabs his crystal ball... What are the contents of Threads.h and Interthread.h? How are we supposed to asnwer this without knowing what's there?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  i don't know the header of boost and can't find it.

Comment: @Griwes thread code is included

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the line `using namespace boost;`. It doesn't appear to be needed in your program.

Comment: When i delete it i got that error `Test.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to Thread::start(void* (*)(void*), void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @user1476982: You need to link against the library or object files where `Thread::start` is defined.