# expected primary-expression before ‘void’

Tags: c++, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined namespace 'boost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170644/undefined-namespace-boost)

Could anyone help me to handle that error. Thanks a lot

```
#include "Threads.h"
#include "Interthread.h"
#include <pthread.h>


void* task1(void *arg) {
// do stuff
}

void task2() {
// do stuff
}

int main () {
//using namespace boost; 
Thread thread_1;
thread_1.start (void *(*task1)(void *arg),NULL);
// Thread thread_2 = thread(task2);

// do other stuff
//thread_2.join();
//thread_1.join ();
return 0;
 }
```

The Error

> Test.cpp:18:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’

Comment: You probably just want `task1` in the function call.

Comment: when i just put `task1` it shows that error undefined reference to `Thread::start(void* (*)(void*), void*)'

Comment: @user1476982: That's a different problem.  You aren't linking against the required libraries.